# Using dplyr functions within a function, problems with NSE/SE

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working in R with the dplyr package, and I need a function for repeated instances where I bin observations along an X variable, and then plot the mean on a Y variable within each of these bins.

Here is a reproducible example of (A) my failed attempt at this function, and then (B) a working example of the desired output with a single X and Y.

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df = data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
                y = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0))

# (A) function that doesn't work correctly
bin_and_plot <- function(data, x, y) {
  data.binned = data %>%
    mutate_(cut = cut(x, breaks = 3)) %>%
    group_by_(cut) %>%
    summarise_(n = ~n(),
               mean = ~mean(y))
  qplot(data = data.binned, x = cut, y = mean)
}

bin_and_plot(df, ~x, ~y)


# (B) working example of desired output
df.binned = df %>%
  mutate(cut = cut(x, breaks = 3)) %>%
  group_by(cut) %>%
  summarise(n = n(),
            mean = mean(y))
qplot(data = df.binned, x = cut, y = mean)
```

I've read the dozens of other questions on here with similar problems, and also looked at these references on NSE/SE...

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html
http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html

...but although it's clear I'm having evaluation problems, I have not been able to resolve them.  Currently, it is breaking on `cut()`--I can avoid this error but then there are multiple layers from problems beyond this one.   I have not been able to successfully troubleshoot, probably because there are several concurrent problems as I have it written now.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: TBH, this is where I ditch `dplyr` and go back to base. There are pronouns coming in future versions that will hopefully reduce some of the finickiness, though.

Comment: construct the full expression you want as a string and `eval(parse` it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where I often start using `interp` from package *lazyeval*.  I think there were some examples of this in the vignette you linked to.  Also, in this particular example, `group_by_` isn't needed.

```
library(lazyeval)
bin_and_plot <- function(data, x, y) {
    data.binned = data %>%
        mutate_(cut = interp(~cut(var, breaks = 3), var = as.name(x))) %>%
        group_by(cut) %>%
        summarise_(n = ~n(),
                 mean = interp(~mean(var2), var2 = as.name(y)))
    qplot(data = data.binned, x = cut, y = mean)
}

bin_and_plot(df, "x", "y")
```

Comment: Worked great, thanks.  I'll have to look into `interp` more carefully

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with the following code. Looks like you needed to remove the `~` symbols and the underscores within the formula.

By adding `x = as.character()` when you define your function you can define the names of the columns you want to use

```
df = data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
                y = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0))

# create a new column to test the function
df$test = rnorm(9,5,2)


# (A) function that doesn't work correctly
bin_and_plot <- function(data, x = as.character(), y = as.character()) {
  data$x = data[,x]
  data$y = data[,y]
  data.binned = data %>%
    mutate(cut = cut(x, breaks = 3)) %>%
    group_by(cut) %>%
    summarise(n = n(),
              mean = mean(y))
  qplot(data = data.binned, x = cut, y = mean)
}

bin_and_plot(df,"x","y")

bin_and_plot(df,"test","y")
```

Comment: @eipi10 I updated the code to reflect your comment. Now when the function is called you can specify the columns you want to use to create the plot